# JavaScript Structure of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, structure

I am currently in the middle of doing my controlled assessment and have finished almost but there's one question, which I really don't get.

**(iii) Describe the structure of an array that could be used to handle the traffic light sequence.**

I've searched all over the and all I'm getting is overcomplicate code and explanations.

The task after **(iii)** asks for me to create a code but using the structure of array that I have described in **(iii)**.

Can someone explain either the array structure I have used or array structures in general and how it works?

Thank you

This is the code I have currently written for the whole task /

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Animated Traffic Light</title>
    <script>
      window.onload = function()
      {
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = colour[0]
      }
      var index = 0
      var colour = [];
      colour[0] = '<img src="../Assets/TrafficLightGreen.png" width="254"        height="501" alt="Traffic Light Red 1">';
      colour[1] = '<img src="../Assets/TrafficLightRed.png" width="249" height="494" alt="Traffic Light Yellow">';
      colour[2] = '<img src="../Assets/TrafficLightYellow.png" width="243" height="506" alt="Traffic Light Green">';

      function changeLight()
      {
        index++;
        if (index == colour.length)
        {
          index = 0
        }
        document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = colour[index];
      }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>
    <p id="image"></p>
    <p>
      <input type="Button" id="button" value="Change Lights" onclick="changeLight()" />
    </p>
  </p>
 </body>
```

Comment: I suspect the question is more about identifying [the sequence of lights](http://www.drivingtesttips.biz/traffic-lights-sequence.html) and expressing that in an array than it is about just identifying the three colours.

Comment: *"...the traffic light sequence..."* Heh - as if there were only one. Even if we confine ourselves to green/yellow/red, in the U.S. it's purely green->yellow->red->green, whereas in the UK and several other countries it's green->yellow->red->red+yellow->green. And that's ignoring arrow lights. :-)

Comment: So you need to describe the model of a traffic light. You can apparently have a color and whether it's turned on or not. Therefore, each array record should contain 2 pieces of info (at least) - the `color` and whether it's `active`.  You can always expand this and add additional info such as what next light will be on after state changes etc.

Comment: Do the previous tasks of the assignment not give relevant details about the scope of the work?

Comment: supporting @Mjh, you should have each record as state of traffic light, means for each light if it's turned on/off ( { red: true, yellow: false, green: false} ) for red+yellow case.

Comment: in changeLight, you can just do a module of 3. that will save the if-statement for you, something like this:
(++index) % 3

Answer (score 1):

A simple traffic light sequence with an array could be done as follows:

Define an array let's say var trafficLight = [
    'red',
    'red',
    'yellow',
    'yellow',
    'green',
    'green'
];

Think of each element in that array as a period of time the traffic lights spend on that particular color. So imagine it's seconds, 2 seconds on red, 2 on yellow and then 2 on green.
You can simulate this by looping through the array.
Make a holder for the color, just a simple div. Set it's default background color to white.

Now loop through the array and set the color for each iteration like so:

```
for(var x=0; x<=trafficLight.length; x++
{
$('myTrafficLightHolder).css('background-color', ''+trafficLight[x]);

}
```

It should now loop through the array, stay on red for 2 iterations, then yellow for 2, then green for 2. Obviously it's going to move very quick, you could use CSS animations or something to slow down the transition.
I have not tested it but it would should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the array elements by specifying index, I recommend using Array.prototype.push() (in this example, it would be colour.push() );

see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp for more info on push().

And also, since the p tag will always contain an image, I suggest placing the "img" tag inside of the "p" tag with the id "image" and use (we will need to give the newly created image tag the id of "image" and remove the id from the p tag).

```
document.getElementById("image").src = colour[index];
```

instead of manipulating the inner html of the p tag like below.

```
document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = colour[index];
```

Below, I have attach additional comments to your code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animated Traffic Light</title>
<script>
// When the window loads, run the function
window.onload = function()
{   // Get the dom object of the p tag with id "image". set the innerHTML to
    // colour[0]. the p tag should now look like this
    // <p id="image">
    //     <img src="../Assets/TrafficLightGreen.png" width="254" height="501" alt="Traffic Light Red 1">'
    // </p>
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = colour[0]
}
var index = 0
var colour = []; // declare new array.
colour[0] = '<img src="../Assets/TrafficLightGreen.png" width="254"        height="501" alt="Traffic Light Red 1">';
colour[1] = '<img src="../Assets/TrafficLightRed.png" width="249" height="494" alt="Traffic Light Yellow">';
colour[2] = '<img src="../Assets/TrafficLightYellow.png" width="243" height="506" alt="Traffic Light Green">';
// Instead of using colour[1], colour[2], etc. I recommend using colour.push()

// When the button is clicked, this function will run
function changeLight()
{
    index++                      
    if (index == colour.length)  // if index becomes 3, reset index to 0 to go to the start of the colour array.
    {index = 0}
    document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = colour[index]; // set the innerHTML of the image (it will keep changing images, since index is incremented per click
}

</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>
<p id="image"></p>
<p>

<input type="Button" id="button" value="Change Lights" onclick="changeLight()" />

</p>

</body>
</html>
```

if you need to change the width of the img, you can do so by using the following code

```
document.getElementById("image").width = "300";
```

The same goes for manipulation the height and alt. Just substitute out width and replace it with height and alt.

Answer (score -1):

Well, for a traffic light you need three colors. So you need an array of the length 3, which means you have the indices: 0, 1 and 2. How you assign the colors is your job (from top to bottom or from bottom to top), but yellow/orange is always in the middle (index 1). So the structure should look something like this:

```
var trafficLight = [
    'red',
    'yellow',
    'green'
];
```

Comment: I mean, OP didn't cited *json*, only array, which is what you're using.